# Simple chat with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to implement a very simple chat with socket.io, and i'm getting into a really weird problem.

server side:

```
var users = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {     

socket.on('join', function(userNameParam) {
    socket.join('chatchannel');
    users[userNameParam] = userNameParam;
    socket.userName = userNameParam;
    socket.emit('firstLogin',users);
    socket.broadcast.to('chatchannel').emit('addConnectedUser',userNameParam);
});
});
```

client side:

```
var socket = io.connect();

    function onLogInLogOutClick() {         
            var userName = document.getElementById("txtUserName").value;            

            // get button text
            var btnLogInLogOut = document.getElementById('btnLogInLogOut');
            var txtBtnLogInLogOut = btnLogInLogOut.textContent || btnLogInLogOut.innerText;
            if(txtBtnLogInLogOut == 'LogIn')
            {
                // send join message
                socket.emit('join', userName);
            }
}
```

When I login in the first browser tab (for the first user) everything works great, but when I login in the second browser tab (for the second user), for some unknown reason 'join' event on the server side gets called more than once!

I've read on the API that 'socket.emit' suppose to raise the event only for the current request socket client, so what can be the issue ?

**UPDATE:**

I looked at the socket.id on the first and second call, and it's the same. why does it happen?

**UPDATE 2:**

On the second tab, when reaching to the server side, I see that the request socket is subscribing TWICE to each event.
I don't know why.

**UPDATE 3:**

Found the problem: server code was placed here:

```
module.exports = function(app, socketio, loggerInstance) {
  io = socketio;
  app.get('/chat',chat);
};
var chat = function(req, res){

    *** SERVER CODE THAT WAS WRITTEN ABOVE ***

    res.render('chat');
};
```

I moved the server code to 'app.js' file and it works fine.

Still I can't figure out why those events were called more than once.

Comment: kinda strange... is it possible that `onLogInLogOutClick()` is being called twice in the same tab? have you tried `socket.on('connect',...)` just for testing when a socket connects? which browser are you using?

Comment: no way.. that's what's strange to me. Right after it loads the page - it registers twice to the event.

Comment: Are you sure the join event is happening more than once? I did a quick test with the code you have, at least something very similar, and it only roins the actual event once. In the debug log it does look like it logs the write for each connected client, not sure why or if that is expected functionality. That being said it did only run once. Could you do a console.log in the `join` and then paste your logs?

Comment: sure.. what do you want me to write in the console.log exactly ?

Comment: ok I found the problem. I'm using node.js for my server, and I'm routing to a relative address 'app.get('/chat',chat);'.
I put all that server code above inside "var chat = function(req, res){ res.render('chat'); }". all that was in my routing js file.
I moved all the code to my "app.js" and now it works.
Still, I can't figure out why it did two writes to the 'join' event.
Plus, now I cannot debug that server code for some reason. Breakpoint inside the 'join' event just doesn't hit.